# Django method to return a dictionary value from request payload

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I have a serializer class like this

```
class HousingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer[Housing]):
    class Meta:
        model = Housing
        fields = "__all__"
        depth = 1
```

with request payload as `[{"id":"1234","created_at":"2022-05-20T15:55:43.611922Z","updated_at":"2022-05-20T15:55:43.611938Z","status":"pending"}]%`

I want to create a method that if giving a Housing 'id', it should return the status from the payload, in this case, it should return the status as 'pending'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the function API View.

```
from rest_framework.decorators import permission_classes, api_view
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny

@api_view(["GET"])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def get_status(request, id):
    try:
        housing = Housing.objects.get(pk=id)
        return Response({status: housing.status})
    except Housing.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And in urls.py, you can add the API method.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('housings/<int:id>', get_status, name="get_housing_status")
]
```